# Space between tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented a button in the ViewController1.
When the button  is clicked in the FirstViewController, I have implemented a tableView along with the items in it in the SecondViewController.

When I add a navigation controller to the FirstViewController there is a whitespace between the cells of the tableView.
 
Thus Creating a messy look to the tableView.

Why is that so
[Before Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaSgQ.png)

[After adding Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xCvE.png)

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of that tableview screen

Comment: Can you show your storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select your UIViewController and deselect "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in Attributes Inspector.

Comment: i have tried it but even then not working..             self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

Comment: @R3MY it will. Run it. Interface Builder doesn't show that property correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your UIViewController and deselect "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bar" in Attributes Inspector -> Extended Edges.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following simple steps:

**1.**

In StoryBoard, Click on your **Navigation Controller**... and see right panel.

**2.**

In the **Bar visibility**..--> uncheck the `shows navigation bar`